# pgAdmin Docker Error: 'gunicorn_config.py' doesn't exist

Tags: docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I updated the version of the pgadmin container, from 4.27 to 4.30 and when I do "docker run" the container keeps trying to start. With the command "docker logs pgadmin" I get the error **'gunicorn_config.py' doesn't exist**.

The container consumes the volume /srv/pgadmin/:/var/lib/pgadmin

Comment: Ever get t his solved?

Comment: did not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The `gunicorn_config.py` file resides on `/pgadmin4` directory on docker container.

The volume mapping don't look be a problem.

Check your docker-compose file. Maybe you have a `working_dir` param or another volume mapping setting that overrides the default `/pgadmin4` directory location.

Check my docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14    
    container_name: postgres_container
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true 
    tty: true          
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes: 
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network

  
  pgadmin4:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    restart: always    
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    stdin_open: true 
    tty: true      
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@example.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - /home/myuser:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/user_example.com/
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network

volumes:
    pgadmin-data:   
    db:
        driver: local

networks: 
  postgres-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```